Issue on Antd css version converting
I have a doubt regarding a Antd CSS which I wrote early in react JS format but I converted it into type script but the Antd CSS is not working properly of the antd package, what can I do? In react I used older version of antd v4.5.3 which contain antd.css page in dist folder.But in typescript I'm using new version of antd v5.16.4 which don't have antd.css page. Thats the issue. Is there remedy for this?

Did you go through the migration guide?
